# Wordpress Salient theme is pushing Shortcodes in Google feed description

Tags: php, wordpress, feed

[Product description is mixed in shortcodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU0k3.png)
I am trying to remove the shortcode in the google feed description. Descpription is not looking very good.If anyone can help , I tried searching on google but its not helping.

I tried searching google and I couldnt find the possible solution. I need to strip the shortcodes from the description. in the google product feed.

Comment: Consider asking this question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/